# importing just parts of modules for the browser with npm and babel

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

I am wondering if it is possible to import just the parts of a library that you need, rather than the whole package.

Example to illustrate what I mean.

```
import {gt} from 'ramda';
console.log(gt(3, 2)); // true
```

I save it, and run browserify on it:

```
browserify a.js -t babelify -o b.js
```

b.js now runs in the browser; but it is 8432 lines long! It imported the entire Ramda library, even though I only needed the content of [gt.js](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/src/gt.js), [_curry2.js](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/src/internal/_curry2.js), [_curry1.js](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/src/internal/_curry1.js), and [isPlaceholder.js](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/src/internal/_isPlaceholder.js).

If instead, I write the example above like this:

```
import gt from './node_modules/ramda/src/gt';
console.log(gt(3, 2)); // true
```

Then, b.js turns out to be 98 lines long.

Is there a way (other than the one I just described) to get around this problem?